# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError inspite of having required jar

Tags: java, tomcat, jar, classpath, noclassdeffounderror

My webapplication was throwing

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/mail/Part
```

I discovered that the webapps/myApp/WEB-INF/lib did not have the relevant jars(mail-1.4.jar and activation-1.1.jar). I manually added them and restarted the tomcat container(7.0.29).

However, I still get the same error thrown when I exercise my app through the relevant flow.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Are you deploying the artifact through a WAR or in exploded mode?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza, I deployed it as a WAR. Later on I manually copied the two jars into the exploded directory(with the WAR still sitting the webapps directory) and restarted

Comment: Try adding the libraries inside the lib folder inside the war. Remove the exploded directory and restart your application server.

Comment: Do you get the same error message in the same part of your application or is now a different error message? Also, have you deleted all the temporary files that tomcat creates when deploying applications?

Comment: Yes to both the questions. By temp files I am assuming you mean the files in the 'temp' directory of the tomcat installation

Answer (score 0):

When this happened to me, i was using eclipse.  I had to go to the menu, click "build all", then go to a file, make a change (i just typed a space) saved the file, then went to the tomcat "server" tab, clicked "republish", then stopped and restarted my tomcat server.  that was the only way for me to guarantee that eclipse would actually compile and deploy the path changes (or imports) I had just made.

Comment: I am not running tomcat inside eclipse. I manually deploy (copy) the war to the webapps directory of the tomcat installation